# The shadow does not follow the shape of the container

Tags: flutter

I'm making a flutter Web App but when I go with the mouse pointer a shadow appears that doesn't follow the shape of the container

```
return ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    Paziente paziente = Paziente.fromMap(data);
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: paddingVerticale),
        child: Container(
          height: 70,
          width: larghezzaBottoni(context),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
            color: Colors.black12,
          ),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text("..."),                
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }).toList(),
);
```

[image]

[image]

How can i control this shading or get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` or `Clip.antiAlias` for your container and wrap your ListTile with `Material` widget:

```
return ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    Paziente paziente = Paziente.fromMap(data);
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: paddingVerticale),
        child: Container(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          height: 70,
          width: larghezzaBottoni(context),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
            color: Colors.black12,
          ),
          child: Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,//for using container color
              ListTile(
                title: Text("..."),  
            ),              
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }).toList(),
);
```

Comment: it's not working, I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @MaurizioMancini also add color: Colors.transparent to Material widget, otherwise it override your container background color.